# Recommendations for IIS book

Tags: iis, admin

I'm a developer who had handed to him the admin duties for our IIS server. I'm reasonably familiar with IIS in terms of setting up web sites, virtual directories, and such and such, but I figure if I'm going to be administrator the server entirely, I better get up to speed.

Any recommendations for IIS books, especially for someone coming from a programming background, rather than a Windows admin background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this one for Server 2008 http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-IIS-7.productCd-0470097825.html

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).